# problema de c++: selection sort

Tags: c++

oi queria uma ajuda para resolver um problema de `c++`:

estou fazendo um codigo e usei o selection sort mas ele esta com um bug na saida de resultados

```
void select_sort (int vetor [TAM])
{
    int menor,aux;

    cout << "Digite as 5 posicoes, de maneira que preencha as posicoes do nosso vetor " << endl;
    cout << " "<< endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        menor = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < TAM; j++)
        {
            if(vetor[menor] > vetor[j])
                menor = j;

            if(i != menor)
                aux=vetor[i];
            vetor[i] = vetor[menor];
            vetor [menor] = aux;
        }
    }

    cout << " o vetor fica assim:" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {

        cout << vetor[i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << " " << endl;
}
```

no caso é uma função
alguem poderia me dar uma ajuda

problema : insiro `1,2,3,2,1`

ele sai : `1,2,2,3,30`

Oque eu faço

Answer (score 1):

Olá, quando você verifica se o menor elemento no sub vetor Vetor[i..TAM] é o próprio elemento Vetor[i], você está utilizando o código:

```
if(i != menor)
  aux=vetor[i];
  vetor[i] = vetor[menor];
  vetor [menor] = aux;
```

Note que, nesse caso, você está apenas atribuindo à variável aux o conteúdo que está em Vetor[i], como o if está sem chaves, toda vez que j incrementar no laço interno, o seguinte código é executado:

```
vetor[i] = vetor[menor];
vetor [menor] = aux
```

Para corrigir isso, altere:

```
if(i != menor)
    aux=vetor[i];
    vetor[i] = vetor[menor];
    vetor [menor] = aux;
```

Para:

```
if(i != menor) {
   aux=vetor[i];
   vetor[i] = vetor[menor];
   vetor [menor] = aux;
}
```